# reactive table display one of two keys

Tags: meteor

I'm using `aslagle:reactive-table`

document : https://github.com/ecohealthalliance/reactive-table

**code:**

```
{{> reactiveTable collection=payments settings=reactiveTableSettingsPayments}}
```

and my setting are

```
reactiveTableSettingsPayments: function(){
        return {
            rowsPerPage: 10,
            showNavigationRowsPerPage: false,
            fields: [
            {
                key: 'new_id', 
                label: 'Payment Id',
                fn: function(value,object){
                    if(!value){
                        //here I want old_id if new_id didn't exist
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                key: 'buyer_name', 
                label: 'Buyer',
            } 
}
```

for the key `new_id` if that key didn't exist in the collection I want to display `old_id`

how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reactiveTableSettingsPayments: function(){
        return {
            rowsPerPage: 10,
            showNavigationRowsPerPage: false,
            fields: [
            {
                key: 'new_id', 
                label: 'Payment Id',
                fn: function(value,object){
                    if(!value){
                       return object.old_id;
                    }
                    else{
                       return falue;
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                key: 'buyer_name', 
                label: 'Buyer',
            } 
}
```